# Android SMS warning pop up

Tags: java, android, popup, sms, message

i'm trying to send an SMS to a short number from my code:

```
sendSMS("5556", "Test");
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

After calling the method Android will show the next pop-up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHErU.jpg

How can I know if the user clicked on send or cancel?

Answer (score 0):

See the [SmsManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) - use the `PendingIntent sentIntent` parameter to determine the result.

Comment: Thanks, but with the PendingIntent i can only see if the message was sent or if there was an error while sending the message. Is there any possibility i can know what the user clicked in this pop up?
http://imgur.com/a/mRLYg